# Regex matching all the giving letter at any position one or multiple times

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regex that matches all giving letter at any position one or multiple times, for example:

if user the input `elol` the result should be:

```
ollie Leola  cello  gello
hello   jello
lobel
lorel   losel
molle   oller
```

right now I have this:

```
.*elol
```

but it's not working because it doesn't match the letters in different positions in the words

the idea came from this site: https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/word-finder-unscrambler.html (just search for words in the Containing the letters (in any position) input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use look aheads for each letter:

```
(?=\w*e)(?=\w*o)(?=(?:\w*l){2})\w+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/l2LtWLnreXd8as).

Note that when a letter must appears multiple times, you must add an appropriate quantifier.

Comment: this is so tricky but it works, thank you :3

Answer (score 1):

You can start the pattern with a word boundary `\b` to prevent the lookahead firing on every position when trying to find a match.

Then you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching optional word chars excluding the one that should match like `[^\We]` and then match the wanted char to prevent some unnecessary backtracking.

```
\b(?=[^\We]*e)(?=[^\Wo]*o)(?:[^\Wl]*l){2}\w*
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?=[^\We]*e)` Assert an `e` char
- `(?=[^\Wo]*o)` Assert an `o` char
- `(?:[^\Wl]*l){2}` Match 2 times an `l` char
- `\w*` Match optional word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ4tY6/1)